# Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c, ubuntu, segmentation-fault, visual-studio-code

Программа написана на языке Си.
ОС: Linux Ubuntu .
Редактор : VSC 2017.
Вот часть кода :

```
while (true)
{
    printf("Введите рейтинг: ");
    char S11[100];
    scanf("%s", S11);
    double v0 = atof(S11);
    if (v0 == 0)
    {
        if (!(strlen(S11) == 1 && S11[0] == '0'))
        {
            Console_clear();
            printf("Вы ввели не число !");
            getchar();
            Console_clear();
            continue;
        }
    }
    mas[j]->Rang = v0;
    break;
}
```

При компилировании все проходит нормально. Однако, при запуске программы, и последовательном выполнении ее пунктов (введении имени, фамилии и так далее), когда доходит до этого места, возникает ошибка Segmentation fault (core dumped). Если же, преобразовать эту часть кода в более простую, например :

```
printf("Введите рейтинг: ");
scanf("%f", &newUser.Rang);
```

Все будет работать нормально, однако необходима проверка на наличие символов отличных от цифр в этой строчке.

В чем причина ошибки?

Comment: "...однако необходима проверка на наличие символов отличных от цифр в этой строчке". Но у вас в коде нет такой проверки. Так "необходима" такая проверка или нет?

Comment: "...когда доходит до этого места..." До какого "этого" места? Что такое `mas`? Что такое `j`? Что такое `newUser`? Почему вы пользуетесь ущербной функцией `atof`, а не нормальной `strtod`?

Comment: Вот эта часть кода и является данной проверкой.
mas - массив значений структуры данных.
j - номер массива, так как таких массивов может быть много.
newUser - структура данных, у нас есть структура user, в которой мы меняем значения, я назвал ее newUser

Comment: Нет. Например, если ввести `123vasya`, то ваша проверка не заметит ничего странного. А если ввести `0.0`, то она скажет, что это не число. Почему? И почему вообще вы работаете с плавающим типом, если вы хотите разрешать только цифры. "Только цифрами" можно набрать только целые значения. Откуда тогда вдруг взялся `double`?

Comment: Да, согласен, проверку реализовал неверно. Не подскажете тогда, каким образом ее лучше всего сделать ? через strtod упомянутый выше ?

Comment: "mas - массив значений структуры данных. j - номер массива..." Ну так а вы проверили корректность этих значений?

Comment: Именно через `strtod`. Но опять же мне не ясно, что именно вы пытаетесь ввести: целое значение или плавающее?

Comment: Это исключено, так как я сам ввожу эти значения. У меня есть код полностью рабочий на С++ и я его переношу на обычную С , и под Ubuntu - там этих ошибок нет.

Comment: В какой именно строчке происходит падение?

Comment: Целое или плавающее - бывает разное. И это не является определяющим местом - сам факт что бы при вводе в строке символов  программа зацикливалась до того момента пока пользователь не введет только числа.

Comment: Если я ввожу символы - мне правильно выводит что я не ввел число. Однако, как только введу числа, моментально падает

Comment: Имея дамп, да на Линуксе - почему просто не посмотреть в gdb, где оно упало?

Answer (score -1):

Два замечания по коду.

Первое. Условие

```
strlen(S11) == 1 && S11[0] == '0'
```

не имеет смысла, так как если в S11[0] находится 0, то длина строки == 0.

Второе. А где присовоение значения переменной j?

```
mas[j]->Rang = v0;
```

Comment: Ваше первое замечание не имеет смысла, ибо в коде сделана проверка на `'0'`, а не на `0`. Не путайте `0` и `'0'`.

Comment: Присвоение починил, однако проблему это не решило

Comment: **ибо в коде сделана проверка на '0'** - виноват, проглядел.

Comment: Ошибка *Segmentation fault* возникает тогда, когда программа пытается обращение к памяти  за пределом сегмента, ей выделенного ОС. Как правило, такие ошибки возникают либо при использовании индексов, вышедших за переделы размерности массива, либо при использовании "битых" указателей.

Comment: В приведённом Вами участке кода есть только одно "подозрительное" место: *mas[j]->Rang = v0;*  Окружите этот оператор операторами типа *prinf("1111\n"); ... prinf("2222\n");* что бы проверить эту гипотезу. Если единички напечатались, а двойки - нет, значит Ваше присвоение j неверно.

Comment: Если же не напечатались даже единички - значит остаётся только *scanf("%s", S11);*. Что-то не так со строкой, которую вы вводите.

Comment: Если же и эта проверка не даст результата, значит ошибка вовсе не в этом месте.